# 06 Toyota Corolla No Brakes

Tags: toyota, brakes, corolla, master-cylinder

I have a 2006 Toyota Corolla with 132k miles. Just replaced the front brakes rotors and pads yesterday. Afterward, I manually pumped them up before starting the vehicle; however, upon starting my brakes, not even spongy, they are non-existent. The first thing I tried was to bleed them rear-pass, rear-drive, front-pass, and front-drive. There were a 'few' bubbles with the first wheel that was it. Again, I started and still absolutely no pedal at all nothing. So, I decided to redo the bleeding and did it a second time to no avail. What else can I test? Is this a bad master cylinder? Or booster? Both the master and booster would be original to the car.

Comment: Master cylinder can cause this, not the booster, if it is bad the pedal gets hard to push.

Comment: What do you mean by "no pedal?" Does the pedal move when you press on it, or does it remain stationery?

Comment: Pedal moves to the floor there is just no resistance at all.